# subversion - Edit url for Repository in Working Copy

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, subclipse, working-copy

I have a working copy for one of my subversion repositories that I use for developing web applications in Aptana Studio.  Everything is working fine when I am in the office on the network, but I'm not able to connect to my repository when I'm connecting via VPN.

I've determined the issue, but I'm not sure exactly how I can fix it.  The issue stems from my repository url referring to my SVN Server by computer name instead of IP address.  For some reason, our VPN won't recognize computer names, but works fine with IP addresses.

I cannot find a way to update the for the repository from computer name to IP address in order for my working copy to connect.  I am using ToroiseSVN and Subclipse plugin for Aptana Studio3/Eclipse as clients.

**To be clear**, my repository has not moved locations, I just want to refer to my SVN server in the url by IP address instead of using the server's computer name.  Every article I've found related to changing a repository url talks about either moving the entire repository or switching the working copy to look at a different repository.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) to change your WC to a different path in the same repository

[`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.relocate) to change the root URL of the repository your WC points to.

Comment: svn relocate did the trick.  I'd seen that before, but I always thought it was for physically moving the repository.

Answer (score -1):

In Subclipse, the option is available in the SVN Repositories view.  Right-click on repository name and choose Relocate.  This lets you change the URL which will update both the repository item as well as any working copies in your Eclipse workspace.